# Spring code-based configuration - IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, configuration

I have found an example of 100% code-based spring configuration here:

```
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html
```

Content:

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
  // Create the 'root' Spring application context
  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
    new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
  rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

  // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
  container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

  // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext =
    new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
  dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);

  // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
  ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
    container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
  dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
  dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}

}
```

In the example above they never called refresh() after registering a configuration class.
But API says - that refresh() must be called in order for the context to fully process the new class.
So I added refresh() afrer each register statement

```
rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);
rootContext.refresh();

dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);
dispatcherContext.refresh();
```

And as a result:

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component    [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:699)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1647)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:465)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:415)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:592)
```

But if I remove refresh() (apparently) it works fine (I use Tomcat 8.0)
In the end I don't fully understand if refresh() must be used in code like this. If not - when should I use it?

Comment: Please post the rest of the stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, this is only important for the `ApplicationContext` passed to the `DispatcherServlet`. That `DispatcherServlet` constructor states

> The given web application context may or may not yet be refreshed. If
>   it has not already been refreshed (the recommended approach), then the
>   following will occur:
>
> - If the given context does not already have a parent, the root application context will be set as the parent.
> - If the given context has not already been assigned an id, one will be assigned to it
> - **`ServletContext` and `ServletConfig` objects will be delegated to the application context**
> - `postProcessWebApplicationContext` will be called
> - Any `ApplicationContextInitializers` specified through
>     the "contextInitializerClasses" init-param or through the
>     setContextInitializers property will be applied.
> - `refresh()` will be called if the context implements `ConfigurableApplicationContext`
>
> **If the context has already been refreshed, none of the above will
>   occur, under the assumption that the user has performed these actions
>   (or not) per their specific needs.**

So for the `DispatcherServlet`, you have to do the following

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);

// will take care of calling refresh() on the ApplicationContext
ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
```

This is necessary for the `DispatcherServlet` configuration because some of the beans generated because of `@EnableWebMvc` (or the equivalent `<mvc:annotation-driven>`) require the `ServletContext` and/or `ServletConfig` objects which are provided by the Servlet container.

The root context should not have such dependencies so it is safe to do

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);
rootContext.refresh();
```

Note that you could just create the `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` object by passing the `@Configuration` classes as arguments to its constructor.