# Spring JavaConfig configuration exception : A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, configuration, spring-java-config

I am trying to replace my web.xml with a pure Spring 4.1.0 JavaConfig setup.  According to examples I've read, and the API docs, the follow 'should' work:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        // Create the root appcontext (replaces the web.xml context-param & ContextLoaderListener)
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(RootConfig.class);
        // since we registered RootConfig instead of passing it to the constructor
        rootContext.refresh(); 
    ...
    ...
}

}
```

With RootConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.ia", excludeFilters=@ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=Controller.class))
@EnableSpringConfigured
public class RootConfig{
}
```

However, when doing so, I get the following error message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at com.ia.system.configuration.WebAppInitializer.onStartup(WebAppInitializer.java:60)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

where the offending line is at:

```
rootContext.refresh();
```

If I remove the `rootContext.refresh()` statement, everything seems to work properly.

This is the same error as specified in [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21356775/827480), however the accepted response seems to indicate that the `refresh()` should work fine for the rootContext.  This is not the case for me.  I am unsure why this is throwing an error.

I have read in a couple of places that you can pass the `@Configuration` class to the constructor instead of calling the `refresh()` method, but I am not sure which constructor that is.  `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext()` does not have such a constructor, so I am a little confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the servlet context before calling `refresh()`:

```
rootContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
```